# How to Show Related Products by Attribute - WooCommerce

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

WooCommerce provides [documentation](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/change-number-of-related-products-output/) on how to change the number of related products shown on a product page. Is there a way to change *how* they are related? It seems they are currently being related by category. Is there a way to show related products based on a single attribute?

Filter Below:

```
<?php
/**
 * WooCommerce Extra Feature
 * --------------------------
 *
 * Change number of related products on product page
 * Set your own value for 'posts_per_page'
 *
 */ 
function woo_related_products_limit() {
  global $product;

    $args = array(
        'post_type'             => 'product',
        'no_found_rows'         => 1,
        'posts_per_page'        => 6,
        'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
        'orderby'               => $orderby,
        'post__in'              => $related,
        'post__not_in'          => array($product->id)
    );
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_related_products_args', 'woo_related_products_limit' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [filter `woocommerce_related_products_args` does not exist anymore](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/13962). You can look into the function [`wc_get_related_products()`](https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_get_related_products/) to find which filters are currently available.

To replace categories by a single product attribute, I used the following code in my `functions.php`:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_related_product_cat_terms', 'my_attribute_relation', 10, 2);
/** Find related products using the attribute `pa_myAttrib`, throw away product categories. */
function my_attribute_relation( $original_term_ids, $product_id ) {
  return wc_get_product_term_ids( $product_id, 'pa_myAttrib' );
}
```

In this case, product related by tags are kept. If you want to alter those, add a filter for `woocommerce_get_related_product_tag_terms`, too.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it by the taxonomy feature in wp_query... [link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters)

The attribute you want to target is 'woocommerce_attributes', not tested but this should work:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type'             => 'product',
    'no_found_rows'         => 1,
    'posts_per_page'        => 6,
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
    'orderby'               => $orderby,
    'post__in'              => $related,
    'post__not_in'          => array($product->id),
    'woocommerce_attributes' => 'attribute_slug',
);
return $args;
```